# Problems with a xml Android layout. The layout overlaps the toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am programming an Android application in Java.

I have the following xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.geologyapplications.minerals.Ficha"
    android:theme="@android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#ffff00"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scr1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txtPregunta"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/resps">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/a"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/b"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/c"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/d"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                </RadioGroup>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ok"
                            android:id="@+id/a1"
                            android:contentDescription="correcta"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/falso"
                            android:id="@+id/a2"
                            android:contentDescription="incorrecta"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ok"
                            android:id="@+id/b1"
                            android:contentDescription="correcta"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/falso"
                            android:id="@+id/b2"
                            android:contentDescription="incorrecta"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ok"
                            android:id="@+id/c1"
                            android:contentDescription="correcta"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/falso"
                            android:id="@+id/c2"
                            android:contentDescription="incorrecta"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ok"
                            android:id="@+id/d1"
                            android:contentDescription="correcta"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/falso"
                            android:id="@+id/d2"
                            android:contentDescription="incorrecta"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/responder"
                        android:id="@+id/responder"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/siguiente"
                        android:id="@+id/siguiente"
                        android:elevation="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,UnusedAttribute"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/finalizar"
                        android:id="@+id/finalizar"
                        android:elevation="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,UnusedAttribute"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the Java class I don't do anything special, I upload the toolbar.

```
public class QuizGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_game);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        toolbar.setBackground(colorDrawable);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//The class is long, it has 400 sentences.
```

In the design view all looks correct, I don't see that the layout overlaps the toolbar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

And the tree of tags looks ok too.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But launching the activity, in the rigth-top part of the toolbar, a white box appear. It is as if there were a LinearLayout behind the toolbar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

How could I modify the xml file so this doesn't happen, and I can see the hole toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

For I can't know your toolbar's style `@style/ToolbarTheme` and any of actions, I test it without setting any style and actions on the toolbar, there is no problem. It may be cause of your `ToolbarTheme`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It is not that. I removed the style in the xml tag and it does the same. I don't know why, the button were pressing the entire layout up. Giving a height to the buttons and removing `android:elevation="0dp"` solved the trouble.

Comment: @Universal_learner Ok, it was good anyway you solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the buttons were pressing the entire layout up. Supressing `android:elevation="0dp"`, supressing margins and giving a height to the buttons solved the trouble.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@string/responder"
    android:id="@+id/responder"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@string/siguiente"
    android:id="@+id/siguiente"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@string/finalizar"
    android:id="@+id/finalizar"/>
```

The toolbar is no more overlaped.

[image]